# django error: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: django, sqlalchemy, arguments

I've written a sqlalchemy model called 'library':

```
class Library(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'library'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    details = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, details):
        self.details = details

    def __repr__(self):
        return u"Library(%s)" % (self.details)
```

Then, inside the views.py file, I've written:

```
def is_lib_empty():
    return len(session.query(Library).all()) <= 0

def populateLib():
    new_libs = [Library('one'), Library('two'), Library('three'), Library('four')]
    session.add_all(new_libs)
    session.commit()

def index(request):
    if is_lib_empty():    
        populateLib()

    libs = session.query(Library).all()
    return render_to_response('../templates/index.html',{'libs':libs})
```

And then I run *python manage.py runserver*, and it shows me an error message:

```
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

What should I do to fix this?

```
TypeError at /
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Exception Location: /cs/wetlab/Limor/workspace/Yeasti/Yeasti/loose_coupling/../loose_coupling/with_sqlalchemy/views.py in populateLib, line 25
Python Executable:  /sw/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/cs/wetlab/Limor/workspace/Yeasti/Yeasti/loose_coupling',
 '/sw/lib/python27.zip',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
Server time:    Sun, 1 Jul 2012 05:50:03 -0500  


Environment:
Request Method: GET

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
['loose_coupling.with_sqlalchemy']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',)


Traceback:
File "/sw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/cs/wetlab/Limor/workspace/Yeasti/Yeasti/loose_coupling/../loose_coupling/with_sqlalchemy/views.py" in index
  39.     populateLib()
File "/cs/wetlab/Limor/workspace/Yeasti/Yeasti/loose_coupling/../loose_coupling/with_sqlalchemy/views.py" in populateLib
  25.     new_libs = [Library('one'), Library('two'), Library('three'), Library('four')]

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Please post the complete backtrace of the exception, so that we can see the origin of the error!

Comment: TypeError at /
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Exception Location: /cs/wetlab/Limor/workspace/Yeasti/Yeasti/loose_coupling/../loose_coupling/with_sqlalchemy/views.py in populateLib, line 25
Python Executable: /sw/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.2

Comment: Python Path: 
['/cs/wetlab/Limor/workspace/Yeasti/Yeasti/loose_coupling',
 '/sw/lib/python27.zip',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/sw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']

Comment: @limlim: Put it in the question so we can see the line breaks!

Comment: @limlim: I suspect you are importing quite a lot of modules using `from <module> import *`, and the `Library` class you are using is not  the one you think it is, but comes from some other module.  Can you verify that `Library` in the code line `new_libs = [...]` is actually *your* class (e.g. by putting a `print(Library)` above, which should read like `<class Library from YOURMODULE>`)?

Comment: Thank you! The problem was indeed that I was using a different Library class!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

You can always use the default constructor, using keyword arguments:

```
Library(details='some details')
```

as described in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html

This is supported by the default constructor, no need to override it. Anyway, your code should work, unless there is some override somewhere...

Comment: I've made a mistake while copying the code here. The correct line is:new_libs = [Library('one'), Library('two'), Library('three'), Library('four')], and it still doesn't work

Comment: Okay, the error says that __init__ expects 1 argument(self). As seen from your code it also expects 'details'. Is this the real code for Library model?

Comment: I've updated the answer. There is no need to override the __init__ method, it supports passing column values as keyword arguments. But anyway your code seems to be a valid one.. No idea what's wrong, at least in the tutorial there is a similar example..